# I sent out a recurring meeting, even though some attendees accepted, their response is still showing tentative. How do I update this?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I sent out a recurring meeting, even though some attendees accepted, their response is still showing tentative. How do I update this? Almost all attendees accepted the invite.

The meeting was set up on laptop and only updated on laptop. I'm sure that other users could have accepted with laptop, Android, or Apple phones. This has only happened one 1 recurring meeting, nothing else.

Comment: If they responded by email instead of clicking on accept, this will always show as tentative. If people don't use outlook, they may not see the option to accept. See also: https://www.cedarville.edu/insights/computer-help/post/how-to-respond-to-a-meeting-invitation-in-outlook

Comment: Also, you should clarify the wording of your question. What do you mean by "some attendees accepted"? Button click, or email?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your mail account? Is it an exchange account?

How do these attendees accept this meeting?

What are clients these attendees using to accept meeting request?

Could you see any updates on outlook.com?

Based on my knowledge, if the attendees accept the meeting request, the meeting status is alive not tentative.